# how to start afresh with database in django. Sqlflush and sqlclear don't seem to work

Tags: python, django

I have 6 models in two files(benef and petition) in addition to the user information. There are some inter dependencies. When I changed the model, there was some error. so I thought  of starting afresh and want to drop all tables.

I ran **sqlflush** and **Sqlclear** with following result.

**Sqlflush** result is

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM "django_admin_log";
DELETE FROM "auth_permission";
DELETE FROM "auth_group";
DELETE FROM "auth_group_permissions";
DELETE FROM "django_session";
DELETE FROM "auth_user_groups";
DELETE FROM "auth_user_user_permissions";
DELETE FROM "benef_beneficiary_information";
DELETE FROM "petition_employer";
DELETE FROM "petition_job";
DELETE FROM "nashvegas_migration";
DELETE FROM "benef_beneficiary";
DELETE FROM "auth_user";
DELETE FROM "benef_beneficiaryname";
DELETE FROM "petition_petition";
DELETE FROM "django_content_type";

COMMIT;
Finished "C:\pyProjs\immiFile\manage.py sqlflush" execution.

Sqlclear benef result is 

BEGIN;
DROP TABLE "benef_beneficiary_information";
DROP TABLE "benef_beneficiary";
DROP TABLE "benef_beneficiaryname";

COMMIT;
Finished "C:\pyProjs\immiFile\manage.py sqlclear benef" execution.

sqlclear petition result is 
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE "petition_petition";
DROP TABLE "petition_job";
DROP TABLE "petition_employer";

COMMIT;
Finished "C:\pyProjs\immiFile\manage.py sqlclear petition" execution.
```

But then when I run the project and go to admin, I still see the old tables and when I click on them, the error related to field comes, which was originally caused by model change. The data is not relevant

```
OperationalError at /admin/benef/beneficiary/
no such column: benef_beneficiary.last_edited_by_id
```

I want to start afresh. What is the solution?

I am using Django 1.8 and Python 2.7

Comment: What if you try to use **./manage.py makemigrations; ./manage.py migrate**?

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: once you clear up with django did you check the database again with an sql client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to start afresh. What is the solution?

The sure fire way, which will delete everything (including your data):

1. Shut down the application (if you are using `runserver`, make sure its stopped)
2. Delete the database from the database server. If you are using sqlite, simply delete the db file.
3. Delete all *`migration`* directories created under your app(s).
4. Type `./manage.py makemigrations`
5. Type `./manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#sqlflush):

> `sqlflush`: Prints the SQL statements that would be executed for the flush command.

It just prints the statements that **would** be executed. It doesn't touch the database (same goes for `sqlclear`). You need to use [`flush`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-flush) instead.

Also note this from the documentation on `flush`:

> Removes all data from the database and re-executes any
>   post-synchronization handlers. The table of which migrations have been
>   applied is not cleared.
>
> If you would rather start from an empty database and re-run all
>   migrations, you should drop and recreate the database and then run
>   migrate instead.